# Varying current density across non uniform conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

Suppose we have conductor having non uniform cross sections so j =(sigma)E according to ohms law
And we know that current through every cross section is same irrespective of the area while current density changes
Now if we extend the formulae it becomes
$\frac{I} {A} = \frac{(ne^2t) E}{2m}$
.... Now n e t and m are same throughout the conductor (non uniform cross sections) while for each cross section A(area of cross section) is different so only thing that can change in order to Keep current same thru every cross section of different area is E(electric field) so

1.)Why is electric field changing and how??
2.) If electric field is diff across each cross section then $dV= -\int{E. dl} $ so potential diff is also different across each cross section of same elemental length (dl)

Please explain me with help of formulas  and maths...I get a better glimpse of concepts that way

Answer (score 0):

Your (first) formula is incorrect because $\mathbf{E}$ is not constant within a cross-section. You have $\mathbf{j}=\sigma\mathbf{E}=-\sigma\mathbf{\nabla}U$ (I assume that the conductivity is the same everywhere within the conductor, and $U$ is the potential) and the current continuity condition $\mathbf{\nabla}\mathbf{j}=0$, so we have the Laplace equation $\Delta U=0$ for the potential. One needs to define the boundary conditions and solve the  Laplace equation.

Comment: Electric field in DC current scenarios typically is constant on the cross-section, the variation is negligible, unless the conductor is really thick compared to size of the circuit. It has to be this way in order for the different integration paths to give the same difference of potential.

Comment: @JanLalinsky real life *planar* examples where akhmeteli's variable cross section setup is significant is a thin (or thick) film resistor of trapezoid shape, or even a square resistor whose metal contacts are narrower than the width of the film.

Comment: @JánLalinský : "the variation is negligible, unless the conductor is really thick compared to size of the circuit. " This is not the only case where the variation is significant.  For example, when the thickness is small compared to the length of the conductor but varies significantly on the distances comparable to thickness. It is sufficient to compare the direction of current density (and, therefore, of electric field) in the center and on the periphery.